# g++ Qt link issues

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I'm having trouble (dynamically) linking with the Qt libraries whilst compiling a C++ project with g++ 4.5.3:

```
g++ -Wall XMLInOut.cpp tinyxml2.cpp -I"C:\Qt\4.7.1\include" -I"$ADTF_ADDONS\adtf-device-toolbox\include" -L"C:\Qt\4.7.1\lib" -lQtCore4 -DtUInt32=uint -o xmltest.exe
```

The output is the following :

```
/tmp/cclJqe9S.o:XMLInOut.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `QString::toUInt(bool*, int) const'
/tmp/cclJqe9S.o:XMLInOut.cpp:(.text$_ZN7QStringC1EPKc[QString::QString(char const*)]+0x15): undefined reference to QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/cclJqe9S.o: bad reloc address 0x15 in section `.text$_ZN7QStringC1EPKc[QString::QString(char const*)]'
```

If I understand correctly, the -l option will link against a dynamic library. in the Qt/libs I have the QtCore4.dll

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

**EDIT** :

Although I believe the problem lies fully in the linkage, I will post my code :

```
#include "XMLInOut.h"
#include "tinyxml2.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "ModelToInterfaceWrapper.h"

//#define __DEBUG_OUT_
    #ifdef __DEBUG_OUT_
#define out(A) cout<<A
#else
    #define out(A)
#endif
using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;



void XMLInOut::readAndParseFile(const char* pFilename){



     XMLDocument doc;
     doc.LoadFile( "config.xml" );
     XMLElement *service   = doc.FirstChildElement( "root" )->FirstChildElement( "Service" );



        for( service; service; service=service->NextSiblingElement()  )
        {// Iterating Services

             out(endl<<service->FirstAttribute()->Value());

             QString serviceName;
             tUInt32 signalValue ;

             const XMLAttribute* description = ((const XMLElement *)service)->FindAttribute("description");

            if((const XMLAttribute*)0 != description){
                out(" ("<<description->Value()<<")");
                serviceName = description->Value();
            }else {
                serviceName = service->FirstAttribute()->Value();
            }



            for(XMLElement *signal = service->FirstChildElement( "Signal" ); signal; signal=signal->NextSiblingElement()  ){
                out(endl<<"  "<<signal->GetText());
                signalValue = (new QString (signal->GetText()))->toUInt();
            }

        }


}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    XMLInOut xmlinOut;

    xmlinOut.readAndParseFile("config.xml");

}
```

Comment: Can you show a simple main.cpp that reproduces the issue?

Comment: ok, I posted the code in the original thread.

Comment: Why are you even allocating a QString object on the heap? Could you please provide a simple main.cpp, like `#include <QString> #include <QDebug> int main() { QString string = "50"; qDebug() << string.toUint(); return 0; }` => Also, try to remove all the red-herring, like `-lQtCore4 -DtUInt32=uint`. Yeah, this is called [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) once you follow that, basically.

Comment: I would highly recommend using either *qmake* or *cmake* to generate makefiles for your project. Also you should be creating an instance of `QCoreApplication` in your main function.

Comment: I am not creating a Qt Application. I'm trying to use some of the provided API, such as QString..

Comment: are you compiling the application with the same toolset that the Qt libraries were compiled with?